# WebDav URL for onedrive for 3rd Party Connection

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, webdav

I am trying to find the WebDAV address to my onedrive folder for a 3rd party application. Where should I look?
My url is something like this.

https://COMPANYNAME-my.sharepoint.com/personal/NAME_COMPANYNAME_com/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx .

As per the Moderator of Microsoft,

"Getting the WebDAV URL for your file needs your IT admin privilege. You are using a sharepoint account through your company, so we suggest that you contact your IT admin to access the WebDAV site."

I am the administrator, I am not able to find the page where I can access the WebDav Site.

Thank in Advance.
Regards
Pratyush SINHA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) Powershell script

The most simple approach is to use `OneDriveMapper.ps1` script, [posted on TechNet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/OneDriveMapper-automaticall-d7d498b0).

Pay attention to the `MANDATORY MANUAL CONFIGURATION` section inside. If you're lucky, the only thing you would have to change is `$O365CustomerName`:

```
####MANDATORY MANUAL CONFIGURATION
<....>
$O365CustomerName = "ogd" # (example, ogd as in https://ogd-my.sharepoint.com or https://ogd.sharepoint.com)
<....>
```

It would automatically authenticate you and show the appropriate webdav url in log:

```
<...>
INFO | Retrieving Sharepoint cookie step 2 at https://ogd-my.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx
INFO | username detected, your onedrive should be at \\ogd-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\username_ogd_com\Documents
<...>
```

You might have to run this script on each logon or so, so that it would authenticate you.

The admin privilege is not required to run the script.

### 2) Manually, via "Open with explorer"

User can manually access his personal folder with a few clicks.

1. Using Internet Explorer (it won't work in other browsers) go to OneDrive web page
2. Switch to classic view (use "Return to Classic One Drive" in the lower-left part of the page; it might be hidden in the Hamburger menu, if you screen is too narrow)
3. Enable Ribbon (Settings -> Ribbon)
4. On "LIBRARY" Ribbon tab, click "Open with explorer"

A [version with screenshots](https://web.archive.org/web/20181024071055/http://blog.ciaops.com/2016/03/mapping-drive-to-onedrive-for-business.html).

Comment: It seems to me that the second option does not work anymore (I cannot find the classic view).

Comment: @RazvanSocol, still work for me. Are you sure you've checked inside the hamburger menu? (I've just edited the answer accordingly)

Comment: The link for Classic View does not appear on https://onedrive.live.com (see https://imgur.com/wvTutlX). However, I did find the link on OneDrive for Business (with an url like foobar-my.sharepoint.com). Thanks!